# kivy app works with wifi but not with mobile net like 4G

Tags: python, kivy, urlrequest

i have an kivy app who works with wifi but not with 4G, i have atached the internet permission in .spec: android.permissions = android.permission.INTERNET, (name=android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;maxSdkVersion=18), and it works! But just with wifi, i suspect the maxsdkversion be the problem (i'm using kivy.network.urlrequest lib)

i tested the app in my school wifi, and doesn't work and with 3G, 4G, its work just with wifi's like my wifi house, i have tried to do this app with requests lib, and works... but just with wifi like UrlRequest, well i want to no what is the problem in mobile internets